# State Space Averaging combined with Static Analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, state-space

In class we learned about State Space Averaging Mathod to analize DC-DC converter topologies.

Therefore we defined a stete vector x containing variables proportinal to the stored energy in a circuit element. Voltage for capacitors and current for inductors.

With a system like x' = Ax + Bu we calculate the small-signal behaviour. The Output of the system was described in the form y = Cx + Du.

With the matrices C and D one can decide how the output of the system is described.

However I'have the problem that I would like to know every current and volatge in my system. For that the output vector y is to small (in my view) because it's holding only variables for C and L and not for resiors, diodes and so on.

In the first semesters a learned about static resistor circut analysis with a system like a = Bx where we have a vector for current, one for voltage and a matrix for the resistances.

Now my Question:
Is there a common way to describe the entire circuit as matrix, derive the matrices A, B, C, D from the whole circuit matrix, calculate a state and plug y back in the whole system matrix to get every voltage and current for a given state?

I know it should be possible because I did this many timed by hand with a system of equations. But, is there a common way how to do it? And if there is, could you recommend some papers or literatimure.

Comment: [State Observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_observer)

Comment: Just a comment, beside state-space averaging (SSA) are you also taught the PWM switch model? This is - by far - a much easier method than SSA which fails to predict that the classical switching cells remain 2nd-order systems when transitioning to DCM. It also fails to predict a RHP zero in the control-to-output transfer function of the boost and buck-boost when operated in DCM. I would advise to look at my [APEC 2013](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202013.pdf) seminar to see how powerful and easy the PWM switch model is.

Comment: Could the second problem not be overcome by introducing a third state per period?

Comment: I'm very interested in the seminar. However, regarding my question it is the same. I'm looking for a solution to describe my whole circuit wirh every component as matrix. So that I'can use this describtion to derive expressions for the smal-signal model and use the result of to calculate every voltage and current to a given time.